# Difference between Select and ConvertAll in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have some List:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

I want to apply some transformation to elements of my list. I can do this in two ways:

```
List<int> list1 = list.Select(x => 2 * x).ToList();
List<int> list2 = list.ConvertAll(x => 2 * x).ToList();
```

What is the difference between these two ways?

Comment: You don't need to .ToList() after ConvertAll().

Answer (score 154, accepted):

`Select` is a LINQ extension method and works on all `IEnumerable<T>` objects whereas `ConvertAll` is implemented only by `List<T>`. The `ConvertAll` method exists since .NET 2.0 whereas LINQ was introduced with 3.5.

You should favor `Select` over `ConvertAll` as it works for any kind of list, but they do the same basically.

Comment: And what about the performances? If I have a List, is it more performant to use ConvertAll or Select?

Comment: @Nicolas: The total execution time is about the same, but they do the processing differently so they fit for different sitations. I added some about it in my answer.

Comment: You can't compare `Select` and `ConvertAll`. The former selects every item in a sequence and you're free to do whatever you want with it.  The latter has a clear intention: convert this item to something else.

Comment: Interrestingly, the List<T> class contains several methods that has almost exact matches in LINQ.

Exists -> Any, Find -> First, FindAll -> Where, FindLast -> Last, TrueForAll -> All

Comment: Difference between ConvertAll and Select is ConvertAll will allocate the size of the list before hand. For a large sequence this will make a performance difference. Thus, if performance is your aim, use ConvertAll. If performance is not a concern, use Select as it's more idiomatic in the language and tells future readers performance was not a concern.

Comment: `ConvertAll` is available for arrays too, using the static `Array.ConvertAll(array, converter)`.

Comment: Since their performance is practically the same, I'd argue you should prefer calls to `ConvertAll()` since they make your intent clearer: You want to take a list/array of [thing] and turn it into a list/array of [other thing]. whereas using `Select().ToList()` can result in side effects. If that is your intent, of course.

Answer (score 114):

`ConvertAll` is not an extension, it's a method in the list class. You don't have to call `ToList` on the result as it's already a list:

```
List<int> list2 = list.ConvertAll(x => 2 * x);
```

So, the difference is that the `ConvertAll` method only can be used on a list, and it returns a list. The `Select` method can be used on any collection that implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, and it returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Also, they do the processing differently, so they have their strengths in different situations. The `ConvertAll` method runs through the list and creates a new list in one go, while the `Select` method uses lazy execution and only processes the items as you need them. If you don't need all the item, the `Select` method is more efficient. On the other hand, once `ConvertAll` has returned the list, you don't need to keep the original list.

Comment: Arguably, one never has to "keep the original list": it will be done as needed by the GC.

Comment: @user2864740: Yes, that is true if the source is strictly a list in memory. If it's read from for example a file then you need to keep the file open until you have processed the result from the `Select`.

Answer (score 46):

The first answer should not be the accepted one. I am a former 2007 C# Microsoft MVP.

In contrast to the accepted response, `ConvertAll` is much more efficient than the combination of `Select` and `ToList()`.

First of all, `ConvertAll` is strictly faster and it uses the minimum amount of memory to do so. Same as Array.ConvertAll vs Select and ToArray. This would be a much more evident with a larger length array or many calls within a loop.

1) `ConvertAll` knows the size of the final list and avoids reallocating the base array. `ToList`() will keep resizing the array multiple times.

2) `ToList` will make slower interface `IEnumerable<>` calls, while `ConvertAll` will loop through the underlying array without extra calls or range checks.

3) Select will create an extra `IEnumerable<T>` object.

Comment: This is no longer correct/accurate. See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/38418#issuecomment-706803864

Comment: As side note VS2019 suggests ConvertAll to replace Select + ToList

Comment: @JohnStock are you sure? My VS only suggests this because i have Roslynator installed (RCS1077 suggestion). If I disable Roslynator, the suggestion is not made

Comment: Roslynator no longer suggests this change since there's no real benefit: https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator/issues/736

Comment: This benchmark I did for .NET 6 suggests that ConvertAll is performing better than Select https://gist.github.com/VaclavElias/b3b521205415d6ae1cf3d5ca9d9cad10. I suggest to do the same tests for your scenarios :)

Comment: @Graham Roslynator does suggest this change, I am on VS2022

Answer (score 0):

I know this is bit late but i have still added because this could be of some use for others in future.

When using it in EntityFramework query expression it is not recommended to use ConvertAll() as it evaluates the expression rather than leaving it as expression for future use. This seriously degrades database query execution performance as it would have to make number of calls before evaluating final expression.

Comment: Not quite. As Guffa points out [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1571839/1364007), `ConvertAll` [is a method on `List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx). By the time you *have* the list, you've already evaluated your expression. But you're right - if you don't want to evaluate all, `Select` is preferable.