# Why does IList<> have fewer features than List<>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

To use such great function as `ConvertAll()`, I have to convert `IList` to `List`, it's painful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that `List<>` is an implementation of `IList<>` with actual storage, i.e. it holds an array in the background. In general, an `IList<>` can be a proxy to something else. In db4o and linq to sql, your `IList<>` could 'point to a query', i.e. accessing the list will trigger a database operation.

This way, you can perform `myList.Skip(600).Take(20);` to perform pagination and only in this step will the actual query be executed. A `List<>` containing a million entries will be huge, while there may be `IList<>`s that have a huge `Count`, but don't eat a significant amount of memory - as long as you don't access the elements.

`ConvertAll` will require each and every object be instantiated so it is a costly operation. Thus, it is better to make the operation explicit and force you to retrieve a specific implementation of the interface. Obviously, conversion requires all objects to be instantiated anyway, so there's no benefit in doing it lazily.

Comment: glad to know about the db4o case, i am using it right now. for db4o case, i shouldn't close the db before use the IList<> right?

Comment: That's right, you'll end up with a `DatabaseClosedException` then.

Comment: Skip and Take are IEnumerable<> methods, not necessarily IList<>.

Comment: That's correct, I was imprecise about that. Since `IList<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerable` and `ICollection`, one gets confused easily :) The interface really only declares `IndexOf()`, an Indexer `[]` and `InsertAt()` and `RemoveAt()`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 12):

Why don't use `IEnumerable<T>.Select` instead of `List<T>.ConvertAll`? Since `IList` inherits `IEnumerable`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571819/difference-between-select-and-convertall-in-c/1571843#1571843) on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Because the interface defines a single behaviour, while a class can implement several different interfaces and also have features not specified by an interface.

If you want the capabilities of the `List<T>` class, don't use an `IList<T>` reference. Use a `List<T>` reference from the start.

Answer (score 3):

Simply because `IList(T)` is an interface, while `List(T)` is one of several classes in the .net bcl that implements `IList(T)` for the purpose of having indexer functionality. Not all classes that implement `IList(T)` will require a `ConvertAll()` method, which is used for converting a generic list of a certain generic type into another.

Answer (score 1):

The `IList` interface is designed to be implemented far and wide. By omitting convenience methods, that means less work to implement the interface and less opportunity to write bugs.

Fortunately, LINQ side steps this and adds a bunch of useful methods through the "extension method" feature. `Select` and `Cast` are particularly useful for conversion purposes. Be sure that you target .NET Framework 3.5, reference the `System.Core` assembly, and have a `using System.Linq;` to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Every method or property definition within an interface compels every implementation of the interface to provide code for it.  If an interface is implemented by ten thousand classes worldwide, adding to the interface a method which would only take one line of executable code to implement would increase by at least forty thousand lines the total amount of code necessary for all those implementations (assuming normal white-spacing conventions).  By contrast, adding a helper method to a class imposes no requirements on interfaces that implement it.

Incidentally, one of my major wish-list items for .net would be a means by which an interface could declare members as having a default implementation via static method (e.g. `IFoo` which includes member `string Boz(int param)` could specify that if the code for a class which seeks to implement `IFoo` doesn't include that member, either the compiler or run-time should auto-generate method `string IFoo.Boz(int param) { return IFoo_Helpers.Boz(this, param);}`.  Had such a method facility existed in .net from version 2.0, it could have probably saved hundreds of thousands, if not million, of lines of code by now, just by having `IEnumerable<T>` include a default implementation `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {return IEnumerable_Helpers<T>.GetEnumerator(this);}`, with the latter method simply being `static IEnumerable GetEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> it) {return it.GetEnumerator();}`.  Such a feature would have allowed interfaces to offer many more features to their consumers without imposing any more work on their implementers.  Further, unlike extension methods which must be statically-bound at the call site, such interface methods would be bound at the implementation, thus allowing implementation-specific overrides to be used when appropriate (for example, if `IEnumerable<T>` offered a `ToList` method, `List<T>` could define a fast implementation which create a new `List<T>` pre-initialized to the proper size and use `Array.Copy` to populate it, and implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` which would return endless sequences could throw an exception (rather than gobbling up all the memory they could get), but most implementations wouldn't have to do anything with that method--they could simply defer to the default general-purpose helper function that would enumerate the items into a new `List<T>` and let it grow as needed.