# Join operation in SQLite in Xamarin form app

Tags: sqlite, join, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new in Xamarin forms. I have created two tables & trying to perform Join operation on these two tables but I am unable to join the table.

I have already gone through these links but no success

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260905/join-tables-in-sqlite-net-with-linq-on-xamarin-android-is-not-supported) [Link2](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36809/joining-tables-in-sqlite-net-and-returning-object-with-fields-from-both-tables)

Can anyone help me how to join two tables in Xamarin forms. Below is my code for JOIN operation

```
public Thoughts GetQueryForAllRecords(int ID)
{
    var q = connection.Query<Thoughts>("SELECT Thought,CreatedOn, AssignedToName, AssignedOn FROM Thoughts JOIN AssignedThought ON Thoughts.ID = AssignedThought.ID where Thoughts.ID=?;", ID);

    return q.Last(t => t.ID == ID);
}
```

But above code only returns 'Thoughts' table recods not from 'AssignedThought' table.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can take a look to [sqlite-net-extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions)

SQLite-Net Extensions is a very simple ORM that provides one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many, inverse and text-blobbed relationships on top of the sqlite-net library.
sqlite-net is an open source, minimal library to allow .NET and Mono applications to store data in SQLite 3 databases. SQLite-Net Extensions extends its funcionality to help the user handle relationships between sqlite-net entities.

```
public class Stock
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(8)]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }

        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]      // One to many relationship with Valuation
        public List<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
    }


        public class Valuation
        {
            [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]     // Specify the foreign key
            public int StockId { get; set; }
            public DateTime Time { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }

            [ManyToOne]      // Many to one relationship with Stock
            public Stock Stock { get; set; }
        }
```

Here's how we'll create, read and update the entities:

```
var db = Utils.CreateConnection();
db.CreateTable<Stock>();
db.CreateTable<Valuation>();

var euro = new Stock() {
    Symbol = "€"
};
db.Insert(euro);   // Insert the object in the database

var valuation = new Valuation() {
    Price = 15,
    Time = DateTime.Now,
};
db.Insert(valuation);   // Insert the object in the database

// Objects created, let's stablish the relationship
euro.Valuations = new List<Valuation> { valuation };

db.UpdateWithChildren(euro);   // Update the changes into the database
if (valuation.Stock == euro) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Inverse relationship already set, yay!");
}

// Get the object and the relationships
var storedValuation = db.GetWithChildren<Valuation>(valuation.Id);
if (euro.Symbol.Equals(storedValuation.Stock.Symbol)) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Object and relationships loaded correctly!");
}
```