# How to join two table values in Sqlite Xamarin form?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have created two models Outlet_model and TbTrdDocModel in my Xamarin from C#.
I can access the values from each model separately but now I want to join both tables in SQLite.
Do anybody know how to join these two model to access the data in the listview?    Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public class MusicItems
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Tension { get; set; }
    public String Category { get; set; }
    public String Subcategory { get; set; }
    public int ResId { get; set; }
    public int LoopStart { get; set; }
}
public class Playlist
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int ResId { get; set; }
    public int LoopStart { get; set; }
}
public class Themes
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String ThemeName { get; set; }
    public String ThemeDesc { get; set; }
    public int ThemeImg { get; set; }
    public String ThemeCategory { get; set; }
    public String ThemeSubcategory { get; set; }
}
public class MusicInThemes
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ResId { get; set; }
    public int ThemeId { get; set; }
}
```

The query:

```
return database.Table<MusicItems>() 
                    .Join(database.Table<MusicInThemes>().Where(t => t.ThemeId == ThemeID)
                        ,m =>m.ResId
                        ,t => t.ResId
                        ,(m,t) => new {mym = m, myt = t })
                    .Select(a => new Playlist
                        {
                            Name = a.mym.Name,
                            ResId = a.mym.ResId,
                            LoopStart = 0
                        })  
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Dear Jay Patel. Thank you very much for your source code. I have tried your code in xamarin form using SQLite.but it is showing that Join is not supporting.Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Seems like SQLite does not support join via Linq
Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260905/join-tables-in-sqlite-net-with-linq-on-xamarin-android-is-not-supported for more help.