# C#: Changing an element from list to uppercase if it contains particular letter in it

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I have the list and need to make them uppercase if they contain specific letter.

I tried to use `mean.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("g");`  but it doesn't work.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           

        List<string> mean = new List<string>() { "dog", "smile", "cat", 
        "bat", "giraffe"};
        // e.g. values containing letter "g" have to be changed to uppercase
        // "dog" and "giraffe" should be changed to UPPERCASE


        foreach (string s in mean)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq with a simple ternary to accomplish this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> mean = new List<string>() { "dog", "smile", "cat", "bat", "giraffe"};
        mean.RemoveAll(item => item.Contains("t"));
        mean = mean.Select(item => item.Contains("g") ? item.ToUpper() : item).ToList();

        foreach (string s in mean)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

The `Select` method will take each element in the list and perform an operation on it. In this case, we only want to perform the operation if the element contains "g". That's where the ternary comes in. If the item contains "g", we return `item.ToUpper()`, and if not we just return `item`. Since the output of a select statement is an `IEnumerable<string>`, we need to call the `ToList()` method on it in order to assign the value back to `mean`.

The output of the above code is:

`DOG
smile
GIRAFFE`

Comment: `mean = mean.ConvertAll(item => item.Contains("g") ? item.ToUpper() : item);` is this correct use of the method?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Although, `Select` is the favored method, as it will work with IEnumerables as well, which you will find come up a lot in c#. If you really want to remove the dependency on Linq, you can use `ConvertAll` to get the same result.

See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571819/difference-between-select-and-convertall-in-c-sharp) for more info

Comment: Also, if you expect you might get an uppercase letter, make sure to add `ToLower()` before `Contains("g")`.

Answer (score 0):

How you expect it to match a *LowerCase* **g** after you already converted it to *UpperCase* **G**

```
mean.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("g");
```

Should be

```
mean.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("G");
```

or even better

```
mean.IndexOf("g", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `foreach` you don't use `mean.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("g");` instead you use `s` as the `mean` is the list, so yes, it'll not work.

Also, `.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("g")` the `ToUpper()` here is going to make the string `UpperCase` so `.Contains("g")` sould be uppercase as well.

you can do this :

```
foreach (string s in mean)
{
    if (s.ToLower().Contains("g"))
        Console.WriteLine(s.ToUpper());
}
```

or if you like Linq:

```
// Linq

var result = mean.Where(e => e.ToLower().Contains("g")).Select(x => x.ToUpper()).ToList();

foreach (var s in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```