# C#: How to express contraint that type can be casted from a string?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following (working) code:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string> { "foo", "bar" };
var ret = stringList.ConvertAll(item => (MyString)item);
```

This works well since I provided an explicit cast operator:

```
public struct MyString
{
    private readonly string _myString;
    public MyString(string myString)
    {
        _myString = myString;
    }
    [...]
    public static explicit operator MyString(string myString)
    {
        return new MyString(myString);
    }
}
```

Now my issue is that I cannot express this as constraints in the following code:

```
public List<T> conv<T>(List<string> stringList)
{
    var ret = stringList.ConvertAll(item => (T)item); // <-- CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'T'
    return ret;
}
```

What `where` constraint incantation am I missing here ?

---

Update:

I specifically used `ConvertAll` based on the following SO post:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55624925/136285

As a side note, I get the exact same error using:

```
public List<T> conv<T>(List<string> stringList)
{
    var ret = stringList.Select(x => (T)x).ToList();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: there is no way to achieve that. You may use an interface `IStringable` or so, though.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you implemented a cast at all?

Comment: if you want to add a library - automapper could help too.

Comment: You can also use Linq `Select` which is likely going to be more readable since it's using standard framework functions.

Comment: constraint ? no ... you may use convention that such class needs a contructor which has string as parameter and then use reflections ...

Comment: @Charlieface That's what `ToString` is for. OP is asking the other way round.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ah sorry, that's what happens when the question title is wrong, have edited it now

Comment: You could use a factory function `Func<string, T>` and pass in `s => (MyString)s`. Not great, but at least it doesn't use reflection

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah, that's what `Select` does...

Comment: I can´t see any benefit in using your conv-method compared to the mentioned select-statement. You don´t need a constraint at all, as `(MyString)s` won't compile if the cast does not exist. All you need is `myList.Select(x => (MyString)s)`.

Comment: @DavidG can you post a MCVE as answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Charliefact suggestion, I implemented the following:

```
public List<T> conv<T>(List<string> stringList, Func<string,T> castFromStringConstraint)
{
    var ret = stringList.ConvertAll(item => castFromStringConstraint(item));
    return ret;
}
```